# How to start manage application screen in android

Tags: android

I want to start manage application(Settings->Application->manage application) screen programatically. I am unable to do it. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

It can be achieved this way:

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent();
intentSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intentSettings);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this could help you

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent( android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS );
startActivity(myIntent);
```